# Auto refreshing a query

Tags: mysql

I have a SQL statement

```
update test_1 set `t_mark` = (`mark_1` + `mark_2` + `mark_3`)
```

which works perfectly but I want the same statement to repeat automatically when a new row is added.

Comment: Why would you want to do that? It's usually not a good idea to store data that can be derived from other data. Create a view with that formula and you'll always have up-to-date information. If you really insist on duplicating data, look into triggers

Comment: The reason is I have a  table named "test_1" with columns "mark_1", "mark_2", "mark_3" and "t_mark". I want the values of mark_1,2 and 3 to be ADDED and stored in "t_mark" anytime a new record is inserted.

Comment: I understand that, but still you are storing data that can *easily* (and without any performance penalty) be derived from the existing data: `select mark_1 + mark_2 + mark_3 as t_mark from test_1` won't be any slower than `select t_mark from test_1`

Comment: If you can use MariaDB (a MYSQL fork), it has `COMPUTED` columns, which would solve your problem nicely, without triggers. (it also offers the option of having the computed column as `PERSISTED` which means actually stored in the database and not computed on each query that needs it.)

Comment: Sorry, not `COMPUTED`, it calls them [`VIRTUAL` columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/mariadb-documentation/sql-commands/data-definition/create/virtual-columns/). But I agree with @a_horse_with_no_name, for such a trivial calculation, storing the results is not really useful.

Answer (score -1):

If values needs to be updated automatically in t_marks field then you can go with Trigger. By using after insert, update on data.

Please find the example for trigger in the below link.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/syedshakeer/how-to-calculate-total-at-the-backend-using-trigger/